# not all code paths return a value c# - word abbreviation

Tags: c#

I have written this code and get the error

> not all code paths return a value.

This works on visual studio fine. But other compilers it does not. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Abbreviator
{
    public static string Abbreviate(string input)
    {
        var pattern = new Regex(@"(?:[ ]|(?=')|(?<=')|(?=\.)|(?<=\.)|(?=,)|(?<=,)|(?= )|(?<= )|(?=-)|(?<=-)|(?=!)|(?<=!))");
        string[] words = pattern.Split(input);

        foreach (var item in words)
        {
            var count = item.Count();
            if(count == 0)
                {return " ";}
            if(count >= 4)
                {var array = item.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
                  return array[0] + (count - 2) + array[count -1];}
            if(count >= 1 && count < 4)
                {return item;}
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am learning a lot from this but the code does not execute as designed now, i.e. it does not cycle through each 'item' within the string, count the chars within it and abbreviate as require. It now simply returns the first item and stops. the code in VS works perfect but my skill in other compilers using 'return' is not good so it is still broken. VS code;

Comment: This code works perfectly as Visual studio console app code;static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          string[] words = pattern.Split(input);
            foreach (var item in words)
            {              
                var count = item.Count();
                    if(count == 0)
                {Console.Write(" ");}          
                    if (count > 3)
                    {var array = item.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
                     Console.Write(array[0] + (count - 2) + array[count - 1]);                 }    else
    {Console.Write(item);}}}

Comment: You might want to go and look into what exactly the return statement means. In essence whenever you use it you are saying "This method has finished and here is the thing to pass back to the caller". It is not 100% clear to me what you are wanting to do though it might be that you want to be using assignment to the array rather than return (and convert to using a for loop so you have the index to use for writing the new value).

Comment: I am trying to string together multiple outputs from the 'words' array as if using a console.write(). I now understand why it fails and only returns the first string pulled from the 'words' array. This works perfectly when all of he 'return' statements are replaced with console.write() statements. But i must use return in this instance.

Comment: You say "i must use return in this instance" but clearly this is wrong because using return as you do doesn't work so I'm not sure what you mean when you say that. A solution and would probably be what I'd do is to use something like a `StringBuilder` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). You can write to this in a similar way to console (see the docs for exactly how to use it) and then after your foreach loop is done you can then call `ToString` on your `StringBuilder` and return that.

Answer (score 3):

As well as what others have said that you haven't got anything for the case of count equalling one the compiler may not be clever enough to realise that your multiple if statements actually cover all possibilities (once they do) and thus it will consider there to be paths through your code that don't return anything.

To resolve this at the end of your method either return something (probably not sensible if you don't ever expect it to happen since if it did you might not realise) or throw an exception. In theory these statements should never be reached but it will satisfy the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
public static string Abbreviate(string input)
```

Your function **needs** to return a `string`.

In your `foreach` loop there are conditions when nothing is returned, so if the loop completes, and the conditions haven't been met, the code currently has no return value. Although this might cover all possibilities of the real world scenario, the compiler doesn't know this, and will complain.

To fix it add a return after your loop:

```
      foreach (var item in words)
      {  var count = item.Count();
          if(count == 0)
            {return " ";}
          if(count >= 4)
            {var array = item.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
              return array[0] + (count - 2) + array[count -1];}
          if(count > 1 && count < 4)
            {return item;}
          //cases that do not return and thus continue to next iteration:
          //count == 1
          //count <= -1
      }
      //ensure we always at least return an empty string if the conditions are not met.
      return string.Empty
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to return some `string` after `foreach`:

```
public static string Abbreviate(string input)
        {
          var pattern = new Regex(@"(?:[ ]|(?=')|(?<=')|(?=\.)|(?<=\.)|(?=,)|(?<=,)|(?= )|(?<= )|(?=-)|(?<=-)|(?=!)|(?<=!))");
          string[] words = pattern.Split(input);

          foreach (var item in words)
          {  var count = item.Count();
              if(count == 0)
                {return " ";}
              if(count >= 4)
                {var array = item.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
                  return array[0] + (count - 2) + array[count -1];}
              if(count > 1 && count < 4)
                {return item;}
          }
          return String.Empty //indicates error
        }
```